# push my UISplitViewController after Login Page in iPad?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

My Application loads login page when it finishes its launch. After login success, i need to navigate from login page to Detail view ( which is a SplitViewController). I have tried pushing the split view but the error reports says

```
 "Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller <UINavigationController:"
```

After Googling i found that the split view controller must always be the root of any interface.

Is their any better solution to display my detailed SplitViewController after the login page?

Thanks.

Comment: yes but you can replace splitviewcontroller as a currentViewcontroller in UINavigationController.

Comment: @RomitMewada can you please describe some more..?

Comment: yes, please try this NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [allViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:split]; you can add or replace
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;

Comment: @RomitMewada thankyouuu so much. can you please put this as a solution. so that i can mark it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers]; 

[allViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:split]; 

//you can add or replace 

self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```

Comment: hey, quick question, so where do you put this? on the first page that is connected to the splitview? as when I dragged my split view on the storyboard it has a splitviewcontroller object that looks like a navigation controller connected to a view controller for the right side and a navigation controller connected to the small part on the right.

Comment: Really? did this work for you @NeerajNeeru? I am getting this exception `UISplitViewControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!`